# How to ALTER multiple tables in mysql with single MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, alter-table

I can alter the tables by writing one query for each in MySQL.

```
ALTER TABLE `nom_table` ADD `images` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `link`
```

But when I am writing many alter statements in single line, Mysql is showing error in syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE `nom_table` ADD `data1` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `link`
ALTER TABLE `nom_table` ADD `data2` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `link`
```

I have to do this in PHP multiple times, so if I run a single query of many alter statements then the server will be very less loaded.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
ALTER TABLE `nom_table`
    ADD `data1` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `link`,
    ADD `data2` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `link`;
```

See the [complete syntax here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html).

However, you **can't** alter different tables in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me......

```
$ContentTables

Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [db_table] => Content_Tips
            [label2] => Tip
        )

/* .... same for 11 more tables... */


    foreach ($ContentTables as $table => $values ) {

    $thisTable = $values['db_table'];

    $addColumns = mysql_query("
        ALTER TABLE $thisTable
        ADD `ranking` INT(3) AFTER `edit_date`,
        ADD `frequency` INT(3) AFTER `ranking` ")

    or die( 'Opps...something wrong in the backroom....'.$thisTable.'...1'.mysql_error());

    if ($addColumns) { echo $thisTable.' has been altered...<br/>'; }
}
```